# How to convert a classic Asp.net webforms to responsive ui using bootstrap etc.,?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, responsive-design

**SHORT VERSION** : Is it possible to convert a classic asp.net webform to responsive ui using bootstrap or jquery mobile with some modifications to the aspx pages. If yes, which is the easiest, preferred way.

**LONG VERSION** : We have an old e-commerce website that was written in classic asp.net. Now the client wants to make the webpage compatible with mobile devices. Is it possible to modify the exsisting aspx webforms and make them responsive? or should we develop the mobile website from the scratch.

Also , I read here http://simpleprogrammer.com/2013/09/03/responsive-design-waste-time/ that responsive design is a waste of time , do you agree to that? , Is creating separate sites for mobile and PC the preferred way?

Comment: Link? My gut says: Skip bootstrap/jquery mobile, leave the HTML alone (as much as possible) and get a CSS developer to make a mobile friendly version using media queries. `* {max-width: 100% !important; float: none !important; position: static !important; }` can often get you pretty far along the path!